# ggplot- change space between bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, spacing

I am sure its a basic one, but couldn't find after even extensive search.

```
No  Status  Val Duration
I1  IS      New 1
I1  IS      InP 2
I1  IS      Re  3
I1  IS      Clo 4
I2  IS      New 20
I2  IS      InP 50
I2  IS      Re  20
I2  IS      Clo 5
I3  IS      New 3
I3  IS      Inp 8
I3  IS      Re  2
I3  IS      Clo 6 

ggplot(df,aes(x = No, y = Duration,fill=Val)) + 
geom_bar(position = position_fill(),stat = "identity",width=0.09) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

How do I decrease the spacing between the bars of I use dodge its unstacking and setting side by side

[image]

Comment: Ignore the parts about `coord_flip` and panel border in the existing answer. In your case, experiment with width and aspect ratio. For example `ggplot(df, aes(No, Duration)) + geom_col(aes(fill = Val), width = 0.5) + theme(aspect.ratio = 4)`.

Comment: @neilws , the `aspect.ratio` is going to change the ratio of image.

Comment: @RanaUsman Yes. But I don't see another way to reduce white space whilst maintaining thinner bars.

Comment: IS there any another way to achieve the same, thinner bar with little spacing ?

Comment: I guess I achieved it by playing around width and  aspect ratio. Only downside is I cant have a dynamic chart. but for now I have a limited set of records so will work for now. Thanks neilfws and RanaUsman

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the widths.

```
    ggplot(df,aes(x = No, y = Duration,fill=Val)) +  
    geom_bar(position = position_fill(),stat = "identity")
```

As you can see, in this case, I removed the `width` argument from your original code.

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Thanks ! All I need is a thin bar close to each other.